# Separar conteúdo da linha no loop do BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho arquivos `txt` com aproximadamente 5 mil itens, e estes não tem um padrão, por exemplo:

```
10 20
30
40

50 60 70

80
90 100
```

Preciso importar isso para o `SQLite`, sendo que cada valor, é 1 registro. 
Exemplo:

```
ID | VALOR
 1 |   10
 2 |   20
 3 |   30
 4 |   40
 5 |   50
 6 |   60
 7 |   70
 8 |   80
 9 |   90
10 |  100
```

Faço a leitura do `txt` da seguinte forma:

```
try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append("\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

No lugar do `text.append(line);` e `text.append("\n");`, teria como enquanto faço a leitura de cada linha, já "tratar/separar" os valores que estão na mesma linha, para que eu possa já trazer separados ?

Se eu tenho 1 valor na linha, eu posso já inserir direto no banco, por exemplo:

`insere(line);`

Mas e com vários valores na mesma linha ?
Por exemplo:

A linha com valor `50 60 70`, eu já faria a quebra dos 3 valores, e executar em um método para incluir no banco?

Se eu uso um `line = line.replace(" ", "\n");` antes do `append`, ele irá me trazer linha em brando, e posso tratar com `if` para inserir ou não. Seria essa a melhor solução ?

*A ideia é fazer isso direto na leitura, para não ter que criar uma variável enorme, tratar o conteúdo, e depois fazer o `insert`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o [split](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#split_33) da `line` e trate cada elemento do array.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = line.split(" ");
    for(String value: values) {
        insere(value);
    }
}
```

Veja uma simulação no [Ideone.](https://ideone.com/XHgR5I)

Comment: Só adicionei `if (value.length() > 0) insere(value);` dentro do for, porque as linhas vazias davam crash.